# How do I solve the 'Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed' error (and others) when using Buildozer on Mac OSX?

Tags: python, macos, kivy, libtool, buildozer

I have built an app using the python language (3.7) with PyCharm, using Kivy, which runs fine within the PyCharm environment. I am relatively new to programming/python and to building an app, so I hope you can help. I made sure the py-part of my app has the name `main.py`, so it can be found easily. I just keep encountering the same errors when trying to build the APK using buildozer.

So far, I have installed buildozer using the following commands in the OSX 'Terminal':

```
$ sudo pip install buildozer
$ git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer
$ cd buildozer
$ python setup.py build
$ sudo pip install -e .
```

I then installed the lld llvm tool as follows (using the 'Terminal' window as well):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project llvm-project
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=lld -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ../llvm-project/llvm
$ make install
```

I then open a terminal window from my app's directory and try to build the APK, using:

```
$ buildozer android debug
```

I've included my `buildozer.spec` file and parts of the Terminal readout for you to see below. Hopefully it will highlight the where I am going wrong.

Here's the `buildozer.spec` file:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Flight Planning Application v01

# (str) Package name
package.name = flightplanv01

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = all

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 17c

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activites = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

In addition to that, here are the warning messages that come in the Terminal readout when I try to build the APK:

```
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[WARNING]: Doing some hacky stuff to link properly

...

ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /Users/JGolding/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/ndk-build V=1

  STDOUT:
Android NDK: WARNING:/Users/JGolding/Desktop/FlightPlanningApp/PythonCode/Drafts/Draft1/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni/application/src/Android.mk:main: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lpython3.7m    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
/Users/JGolding/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/build/core/build-binary.mk:688: Android NDK: Module main depends on undefined modules: python_shared

...

  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=flightplanv01 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/Users/JGolding/Desktop/FlightPlanningApp/PythonCode/Drafts/Draft1/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21

...
```

There is a lot more text generated but in the interest of not clogging the question, I have included only this.

I noticed that OSX has its own 'libtool' and 'libtoolize' tools, so when they are downloaded as I have done, they are automatically renamed 'glibtool' and 'glibtoolize'.

Could this be the cause of the issue? If so, how do I solve it?

I am really not sure how to sort this and to get the APK to build, so I am hoping you can help. I have seen other similar threads and have tried their advice but it still isn't working. Thanks!

**Update: Here's the link to the complete error code. I can't fit it onto this question directly, so I had to put it onto a page of my website.
[Link to Buildozer output error log][1]
  [1]: https://apilotslens.com/error-code **

Comment: Post the full log. Everything you chose to give is a warning, not an error.

Comment: Of course, thanks. I'll run the code now to get it. It's quite a beefy log though!

Comment: I've just added a link to the full error log from the terminal window, as a page on my website, since it is so long that I can't fit it into the question here. I hope you can make sense of where I am going wrong from it!

Comment: You have some linker errors trying to find the compiled Python. I'm not sure why. It could be macOS-related, there have been some fixes for macOS recently. You can try these by setting the p4a.branch token to "develop" in buildozer.spec, but you will also need to update your NDK to version 19. The simpler option is to wait for the next p4a release (within a few weeks), at which point buildozer should update the NDK for you.

Comment: Ah right, I see. I can try and manually update the NDK at least and if that doesn't work, then wait for the next p4a release. If I could, I'd prefer to clean install it again, since I think it has got a little messy. Also, I read some people saying it might have something to do with an 'autoconf.sh' file. I can't seem to find one on my computer. That wouldn't be an issue would it?

Comment: I've now managed to upgrade the components to the latest versions (including Anrdoid NDK to r20 and p4a). Now though, since the newest p4a doesn't support python 2.7, buildozer fails at the first huirdle. I have python 3.7 installed but buildozer won't find it. How do I get buildozer to build using python 3.7 and not 2.7?

Comment: Uninstall buildozer, then install it with Python 3.

Comment: I'll give that a go. I have only tried installing buildozer with pip, not pip3, so far, so maybe that'll sort it. It's just strange how the instructions for installing it with target python3 made no mention of pip3

Comment: We could probably improve the instructions, but in general it's assumed that you're using a pip associated with the Python version you want to install to. It's often the case in e.g. most linux distros that the main python3 installation will have associated tools named pip3 etc., but this isn't a hard rule. In some distros, or simply in other circumstances like within a virtual environment, using pip would use Python 3.

Comment: So I went through the process of uninstalling and reinstalling the different components, with pip3.7. Everything installed fine with that. Whether I use Android NDK r17c, r19c or r20, I am getting new errors now and I've never seen/heard of them before. The first is ``no module named 'silex'``. I don't know what that is but when I then tried to install it, the installation fails, with the error ``pypandoc module not found``. I successfully installed ``pypandoc`` code but the error still appears. Have you got any ideas as to what is causing this? I feel like I'm going round in circles...

Comment: Post the full log as a new question. I have no idea what is causing these issues, since neither buildozer nor p4a uses either of those modules, so it's probably something at your end.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that as soon as I can today.It did seem quite strange that this was all of a sudden appearing, when it hasn't before. I'd certainly like to get to the bottom of this soon!

Comment: I've just posted the question now. The full logs again have too many characters though to post directly in the question, so I have added a link to each one on my website. I hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: I tried `brew install pkg-config autoconf automake libtool` and it got me across the `libtoolize` error.